# Infinite lazy-sequence of events from external feed

Tags: clojure

Say I have a function, `(get-events "feed")`, that returns a vector of events in chronological order, taken from an external source.

Now, at any given moment, that function returns a list of events up to that point in time. Called a few seconds later, it will return a few more events, etc, as the feed continually grows.

If I want to create a lazy-seq that forever pulls new events from the feed, making sure it doesn't repeat those that have already been seen, how would I write this? I'm running into a stack overflow error when I don't use `recur`, but I can't use recur, because it doesn't appear in a tail position.

```
(def continually-list-events
  ([feed] (continually-list-events feed (hash-set)))
  ([feed seen]
   (let [events-now (get-events feed)]
     (into (remove seen events-now)
           (lazy-seq
             (continually-list-events feed
                                      (into seen events-now))))))
```

You can see I'm trying to use an accumulator to track events already seen (in a set), and I'm making sure to always filter out the ones I've seen.

Answer (score 2):

If each step keeps track of how many events have been received so far then that iteration can return a sequence of new events by dropping the old ones.

```
user> (->> (iterate (fn [[events-so-far contents]]
                      (let [events (get-events)
                            new-events (drop events-so-far events)]
                        [(count events) new-events])))
           (mapcat second))
```

Then you can drop the counts from the sequence and flatten the chunks of events into a sequence of single events.

In your example the stackoverflow is because there is no call to `cons` after the call to `lazy-seq` so it's calculating the whole list *as* the first item in the sequence.

```
user> (defn example [x] (lazy-seq (cons x (example (inc x)))))
#'user/example
user> (take 5 (example 4))
(4 5 6 7 8)
user> (defn example [x] (lazy-seq  (example (inc x))))
#'user/example
user> (take 5 (example 4))
... long pause then out of memory ...
```

PS: using lazy-seq directly is somewhat uncommon, though it's important to know how it works.

Comment: Thanks for helping me think differently: `(distinct (flatten (repeatedly #(get-events "feed"))))` -- I think this will do what I want, without the need for me to track the events manually. Not sure about efficiency, but this is just for a command line app and it will terminate after a few minutes of tracking events.

Comment: There's no need for `flatten` here (as there usually isn't), and it makes things more difficult if you want to extend this code to work on any kind of collection-like object. Instead of `(flatten (map second ...))`, just write `(mapcat second ...)`.